# Using IBM.Socket-IO C# library

Tags: socket.io

I am referring to following Socket.IO C# library. In the example there is class referenced named SampleHttpClientFactory.

Does anybody have class definition for SampleHttpClientFactory in C#.

https://github.com/IBM/socket-io